# how to create this popu menu widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, popupwindow, popupmenu

I need help in creating this type of popup window or popup menu in flutter. In which i will use ExpansionTile to show countries and cities.
[popup menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq7qP.png)

Comment: you need to show your attempt when asking questions in SO, otherwise it's people doing your work for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to take 'ExpensionTile' in a container like below code:

```
  ExpansionTile(
                title: new Text(vehicles[0].title, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.normal, color: Colors.black),),
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Column(
                    children: _buildExpandableContent(vehicles[0]),
                  ),
                ],
            ),
```

And call this method:

```
    _buildExpandableContent(Vehicle vehicle) {
    List<Widget> columnContent = [];

    for (String content in vehicle.contents)
      columnContent.add(
          new Container(
            height: 50,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 0),
                    child: new Image.asset('assets/images/demo.png', scale: 1.5,),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 0),
                    child: new Text(content, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.normal, color: Color(0Xff004FBA), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 140, top: 0, bottom: 10),
                    child: new Text(content, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.normal, color: Color(0Xff767676), fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,),),
                  )
              ],
            ),
          )
      );

    return columnContent;
  }
```